# access lower and higher 4 bits in type and bind field in elf symbol

Tags: c

What is the best way to access the low-order and high-order 4 bits of the char type and binding field in the elf symbol struct so that I may compare it to STT_FUNC, STT_OBJECT, STB_LOCAL, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ELF definition](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/1998-04-29/ch4.symtab.html) actually gives C macros for doing this:

```
#define ELF_ST_BIND(i)   ((i)>>4)
#define ELF_ST_TYPE(i)   ((i)&0xf)
```

(Note that these expect that you have defined the `st_info` field as `unsigned char`, not just `char`).